# Javascript onLoad function

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to use a function that prints a string slow in sequence on a page once the page has loaded. Something like this:

"W, E, L, C, O, M, E , T, O, M, Y, P, A, G, E"

Any suggestions where i can find a guide?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried searching for this on Google yet?

Comment: You have already split your query into multiple questions that you could easily answer with a web search; "How do I run JavaScript on page load?", "How do I output to page?" and "How do I run JavaScript on intervals/over time/procedural?". The experts here at SO are here to help if you have a question about specific code, not to provide recommendations for an entire piece of functionality.

Comment: read about window.onload function, setInterval function and document.innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `SetInterval` function .split the string with `space` the apply the array with setInterval with  time delay

```js
var a = "WELCOMETOMYPAGE";

window.onload = function() {
var arr = a.split('');
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  
  if (arr.length > i) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<span>' + a[i] + ',</span>';
  }
  i++;
}, 500);
}
```

```css
span {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this with a clever use of setInterval

```
var welcome = "Welcome to my page";
var index = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(index <= welcome.length) {
        console.log(welcome.substr(0,index))
        index++;    
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

But of course instead of console.log update your page element. I'm using console.log so that you can quickly test this code.

So substitute:

```
console.log(welcome.substr(0,index))
```

With:

```
document.getElementById("element_id").textContent=welcome.substr(0,index)
```

Alternatively you could use a library like Greensock which is very good at sequencing stuff. In fact they even have a function that does exactly that:
https://greensock.com/

UPDATE:

Of course all of this has to be inside a window onload function to make sure it executes after the page has loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var welcome = "Welcome to my page";
    var index = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(index <= welcome.length) {
            document.getElementById("element_id").textContent=welcome.substr(0,index)
            index++;    
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

SUMMARY:

Study

1. How to execute javascript code after the page has loaded
2. How to use setInterval in javascript
3. How to update dom elements using javascript (study jquery as well while you at it)